# ASP Classic not using correct formatting for dates and currency

Tags: windows, iis, asp-classic

I have set the correct region for Windows via the control panel and rebooted the machine.

I have also set ASP.net's Culture setting in IIS, although I'm not sure if this has any effect on ASP Classic.

Yet `formatDateTime` and `formatCurrency` are still outputting US formatting instead of UK formatting.

Where else is this set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in classic ASP you need to set the [`LCID` variable](https://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/date-time-settings.htm) to the locale code of your preference

a good way to place such setting is in the `Session_OnStart` call

```
Sub Session_OnStart

  Session.LCID = 2057 ' 2057 is for English UK

End Sub
```

You can see all available codes on [Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx)

Comment: Why would I need to set this on a new installation of an app, and not on the old?

Comment: I've done what you suggested and now the currency is coming out as, "Â£".

Comment: #balenxandre is right, I just don't know why he is using **sub session_onstart** anyway take a look at [LCID on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_lcid.asp) hope this help!

Comment: @Ian about the "Â£" you should fix your encoding, try with utf8 [Classic ASP and utf8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453864/classic-asp-and-utf-8)

Comment: Try `Session.codepage = 65001` to get your £ symbol to display correctly.  it should go underneath your Session.LCID definition

Comment: Why would elsewhere in the app, the currency be correct?

Comment: @Vixed I always use server events: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ev_sess_onend_onstart.asp

Comment: @balexandre ok, but for me, and I mean only for my idea, it seems to be an old old way to use classic asp.

Comment: @balexandre - Presumably your subroutine is supposed to go in global.asa - if so it might be worth saying so explicitly.