# Different Output Characters on VBScript and PHP in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: php, vbscript, character, ascii, command-prompt

Forgive me for the title. I am a beginner in programming, and I have two codes that do the same task, which is print the characters with ASCII values 240..255 in Windows Command Prompt. One is in PHP

```
<?php 
    for($n=255; $n>=240; $n--){ 
        echo chr($n);
    } 
?>
```

And the other in VBScript

```
For n = 255 to 240 Step -1
     WScript.Stdout.Write Chr(n)
Next
```

But the output characters are different.
[image]

Why is that different? Is it because of character encoding thingy?

Comment: What encoding do you use?maybe to use utf-8 encoding?

Comment: I do not know how to get it, because I am beginner in programming. What I know is that in php.ini file, I only see "iso-8859-1" alongside with "encoding". Also, chcp in cmd gives 437 (if that helps).

Comment: php header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');   http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_utf8_encode.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453864/classic-asp-text-substitution-and-utf-8-encoding maybe useful for asp

Comment: Hmm... But are they the "same" characters (I mean in the picture), just different in encoding?

Comment: The top one is Dos or OEM and the second is ANSI. Use Charmap under Windows Accessories to see. But there will be conversion and those characters in the second output will have been converted to Dos, so the first character goes from ANSI 255 to Dos 152 and that's what is showed to you.

Comment: @dimis283 why is this even remotely helpful? The OP is using a command prompt the process for encoding is completely different.

Comment: What happens if you use `chcp 28591`?

Comment: I want to ask different question, independent from what you see: What do you like to see as result?

Comment: Also as VBScript is Unicode it has probably been converted Unicode to Dos. But US ANSI is the same as first 256 characters in Unicode.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. @Lankymart the VBSCript is now the same as in PHP :) .

Comment: @Noodles thanks for explaining; I really need to learn more.

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit Hmm... nothing, I am just experimenting... Thanks!