# How to read an Excel file from VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, xlsx, filesystemobject

I am trying to read an Excel file in VBScript, but in the `file.Readline` I am getting strange characters. Do you have any idea how you could get the value of the cells correctly? Without Excel libraries.

```
Dim fso,file
Set fso  = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")        
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("C:\myFile.xlsx",1)
row = 0
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.Readline
    dict.Add row, line
    row = row + 1
Loop
file.Close
```

Comment: `FileSystemObject` methods are for processing text files. Excel workbooks are not text files.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/simply-coded/758e2557ccd1a55b46765d8bb1099ec6). Unless you are trying to do this on a computer which does not have excel installed, in which case it will probably be very difficult.

Comment: See ADO which will treat excel files as a database. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-w and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257819/how-to-use-ado-with-excel-data-from-visual-basic-or-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using the extension .CSV, since this allows me to read the information as a .txt in which each column is separated with commas by default, so my code works normally.

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing a macro in excel (Also visual basic script) there are more than one way getting a cell value.
There are range function 
(example from web:) Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Value 
There is cells function (example from web) Cells(1, 1).

The excel file (xslx) should be actually zip file where data is xml.
I think thats why you can't read it if you are using VB compiler.

Comment: Excel macros are written in VBA, not VBScript. The languages, despite being similar, have some notable differences.

Comment: VBA has changed quite a bit ever since I studied it used to be quite similar

Comment: The excel object model, is the same vbscript/vba or any other COM program. Although the way to connect to it may be different.

Comment: The languages are very similar. But like I said, there are [notable differences](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml), and have always been.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to have set the encoding for the page to UTF-8. See the links before for a simple description:

[Classic ASP text substitution and UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453864/classic-asp-text-substitution-and-utf-8-encoding)
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_charset.asp

So it would look something like below, located near the top of the page:

```
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
```